How do I replace a value in ASP.NET Core Web API appsettings.(qa/dev/staging/prod).json with the value from Azure Keyvault?
I have appsettings.(test/staging/prod).json and it contains a password field in JSON, as shown here:
{ 
    "database:      
        { 
             "password" :"some_value"
        }
}

I have stored the password in Azure Keyvault by specifying "database--password" as key name and value with password.
In my program.cs file, I am retrieving the password via AddAzureKeyVault extension and I can see the password is retrieved successfully from Azure Keyvault.
Now how do I map the password value retrieved from Azure Keyvault into the appsettings.json file?
After Azure Keyvault retrieval happens, how to automatically push the password value into json below, so that code can access it?
{ 
    "database: 
         { 
             "password" :"**password_from_azure**"
         }
} 


Instead of pushing the value to json file, you can dierctly retrieve the new value from KeyVault using KeyVault reference.Refer this SOThread and MSDoc once.

OR if you only want to push the value to json file, you need to push the value to EnvVariable and retrieve from there.Refer this SOThread

To push the value directly to appsetting.json value , set the retrieved KVValue to env variable `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("KVVal", kvval);
var app = builder.Build();
var myconfig = new ConfigurationBuilder()
.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true)
.AddEnvironmentVariables()
.Build();
var kv = builder.Configuration["KVVal"];`

Is your issue resolved ?

@Harshitha no it did not, Thanks for your help

Did you get a chance to look into the below sol?Can you Please share more details what is the blocker.

To push the value to appsettings.json, the file must contain the same key with dummy/empty value in it.
 "database": {
   "password": "sample val "
 }

Retrieved KeyVault Value:
var kvval = "Value from KeyVault";


Once the Key Vault value is retrieved, set the value to Configuration.

builder.Configuration["database:password"] = kvval;
var app = builder.Build();
var conn= new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();


Retrieve in Controllerusing IConfiguration

 public IConfiguration myconfig;
 public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger,IConfiguration config)
 {
     _logger = logger;
     myconfig=config;
 }
var KVVal= myconfig["database:password"]

Output:

